# Elegant Number Button in android studio implementation

Tags: java, android

i have problem in this library 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
and someome told me:

That library has not been updated in a few years.

there is a library can i use it , to use the  elegant  number  button in (android studio with java)

please  help !!!!

Comment: What difference does it make if something has not been updated?  Does it do the job?\

Comment: no doesn't work

Comment: Well, that's your actual problem then. Not that "someone told  you it hadn't been updated".

Comment: Please paste your code as text not images